# SQL DISTINCT TOP 30

Tags: sql-server

I need to set a DISTINCT on column "productid" from my query below:

```
SELECT TOP 30 s.fid, s.productid, s.partsreplaced, s.labor, p.part_number, p.name, p.img_small, p.discontinued 
FROM frequentrepairs s 
INNER JOIN products p ON s.productid = p.id     
ORDER BY p.part_number ASC
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT TOP 30 s.fid, s.productid, s.partsreplaced, s.labor, p.part_number, p.name, p.img_small, p.discontinued 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT productid FROM frequentrepairs) frequentrepairs s 
INNER JOIN products p ON s.productid = p.id     
ORDER BY p.part_number ASC
```

Sorry about not providing data sample. Here's what my table FrequentRepairs look like:

[image]

So basically, I don't want to display the same "productid" twice.

Comment: And what happened? We have no idea what your data looks like or what your output looks like.

Comment: What in english are you trying to accomplish?  you can't distinct a single field. Table FrequentRepairs seems to have several parts which may all tie back to a single product which is why you're getting multiple product ids...  provide some sample data and expected result to help tell the store of what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: Do you want 1) 30 arbitrary rows, each with a unique product ID? 2) all rows that belong to the TOP 30 product IDs? 3) something else entirely? Divining the desired output from incorrect SQL is hard.

Comment: When I try FROM (SELECT DISTINCT productid FROM frequentrepairs) frequentrepairs s, I get Incorrect syntax near 's'.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Over:
The problem I'm having is I don't understand the question/problem yet.

Assuming:

1. Products.ID is a Primary Key .
2. FrequentRepairs.ProductID is a Foreign Key to Products.ID
3. The relationship between products and FrequentRepairs is a 1 to Many
4. The overall goal of what you're trying to achieve is a list of the top 30 parts involved in the most repairs?

.

```
SELECT TOP 30 
       max(s.fid) as max_fid
     , p.productid
     , max(s.partsreplaced) as partsReplaced --(just picking 1)
       --if it needs to be coorlated to the max_FID then we would have 
       --to dos something different 
     , sum(s.labor) as Sum_labor
     , p.part_number
     , p.name
     , p.img_small
     , p.discontinued 
FROM frequentrepairs s 
INNER JOIN products p 
  ON s.productid = p.id     
GROUP BY p.Part_number, P.Name, p.img_small, p.Discontinued, 
ORDER BY count(p.part_number) DESC, part_number ASC
```

Comment: had `frequentrepairs s` removed the `frequentrepairs`

Comment: actually, it think it should be FROM (SELECT DISTINCT productid FROM frequentrepairs s) but now I get an error on the INNER JOIN (expecting AS, ID or QUOTED_ID)

Comment: no the s on the inside falls out of scope so the select s.fields will fail.  Really I needed to remove the subquery and just join to frequentrepairs.

Comment: Hi xQbert. I'm still unclear as to how this query would work. Is the query you have here above the correct way to write this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: In plain English, what are you trying to achieve?  Do you want a list of the 30 products involved in the most repairs? summing the labor hours involved.  Provide expected results with your question to help us understand the context of what you're trying to achieve.  my first attempt was a all out guess; but seems to have missed the target.   By providing expected results, and a English context/requirement summary, we can figure this out.